# Bootstrap elements displaying incorrect at form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap framework, but I already made some stuff and it worked fine, but I can't realize what is wrong with this new form I'm doing. Please help me with this one:

```
<%--REGISTER FORM--%>
    <form id="formCadastro" role="form" action="">
    <div class="row" id="faixaCentral">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-centered" id="colunaFormulario">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="form-horizonal" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Cadastro</legend>
                        <%--/*COUNTRY SELECTION AND DOCUMENT/*--%>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span class="help-block">Selecione seu país: </span>
                                    <select class="form-control" style="width: 190px">
                                        <option>Brasil</option>
                                        <option>Argentina</option>
                                        <option>Paraguay</option>
                                        <option>Outro</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span class="help-block">Número do Documento: </span>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDocument" placeholder="CPF" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <%--/*EMAIL SELECTION/*--%>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmailLogin" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                                Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmailLogin" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Results in:

[image]

As far as I know, form-groups should work as rows, but it looks like the email form-group isn't creating a new row. I already tried adding rows as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I don't think that form groups were intended to enclose columns. They're mostly to keep labels and inputs together. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

Comment: For me this form look exactly as you coded it. What do you want to achieve in this form?

Comment: "Email" label should be aligned and closer to the "email" input. And the form-groups should have some distance between them :/

Comment: @isherwood The documentation says they work as new rows: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: Yes, but not across columns, which are higher-level divisions. Your labels corresponding inputs should be in the same columns.

Comment: If you take a look at Horizontal Form example  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal
"Email" input and label are on different columns, but aligned together. And password label+input have vertical spacing, that is what i'm looking for :/